# out of two columns take the greatest column name in r

Tags: r

I have a df in R say looks like this

```
Nay | Yay
 ------
0.05 | 0.95
 --------
0.06 | 0.94
 ---------
0.7  | 0.3
 --------
0.8  | 0.2
 --------
```

outcomes have to be in another column and it should be like. It should take greater column name

```
Nay/Yay
------
Yay
----
Yay
----
Nay
---
Nay
---
```

In R
Thank you

Comment: Just do `names(df1)[max.col(df1, 'first')]#[1] "Yay" "Yay" "Nay" "Nay"`

Comment: There is even a `ties.method` argument in `max.col` so you can handle ties...